# Why is so slow BST (Binary Search Tree)

Tags: python, tree, binary-search-tree

```
class BinaryNode:
    def __init__(self,data,left=None,right=None):
        self._data = data
        self._left = left
        self._right = right
    @property
    def data(self):
        return self._data
    @property
    def rnode(self):
        return self._right;
    @property
    def lnode(self):
        return self._left
    @rnode.setter
    def rnode(self,value):
        self._right = value
    @lnode.setter
    def lnode(self,value):
        self._left = value

class BST:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self._r = BinaryNode(data)
    def add(self,data):
        c = BinaryNode(data)
        q = self._r
        while(1):
            if(q.data == data):
                break
            if (q.data > data):
                if not q.lnode is None:
                    q = q.lnode
                else:
                    q.lnode = c
                    break
            else:
                if not q.rnode is None:
                    q = q.rnode
                else:
                    q.rnode = c
                    break

    def search(self,data):
        return self._search(data,self._r)

    def _search(self,data,node):
        if not node :
            return None
        if(node.data == data):
            return node
        if(data < node.data):
            return self._search(data,node.lnode)
        self._search(data,node.rnode)
A = BST(1)

for i in range(2, 5001):
    A.add(i)
```

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

struct nod
{
 int val;
 nod *st , *dr;
};
typedef nod * Arbore;
Arbore cautare(Arbore r , int x);
void Inserare(Arbore & r , int x);
int main()
{
 Arbore R = NULL;
 for(int i = 1 ; i<=5000;++i)
     Inserare(R,i);
 return 0;
}

Arbore cautare(Arbore r , int x)
{
 if(!r) return NULL;
 if(x>r->val) return cautare(r->dr,x);
 return cautare(r->st,x);
}

void Inserare(Arbore & r , int x)
{
 Arbore p = new nod , q = r;
 p->val = x;
 p->st = p->dr = NULL;
 if(r == NULL)
 {
     r = p;
     return;
 }
 while(1)
 {
     if(q->val == x)
     {
         delete p ;
         return;
     }
     if(x < q->val)
         if(q->st)
             q = q->st;
         else{
             q->st = p;
             return;
         }
     else
     {
         if(q->dr)
             q = q->dr;
         else{
             q->dr = p;
             return;
         }
     }
 }
}
```

**When I tried to insert 5000 vertex * , into BST i got a 14.5 s  . I've tried more ways to improve speed but I can't . Usually I code in C++ and maybe is some code ineficient in python , idk  . I accept any suggestion and i will be thankfull . I put also C++ code which is more faster than python code and I think is pretty same .**

Comment: This tree isn't self-balancing, and you're inserting the data in increasing order, so you're getting the worst-case performance for an unbalanced tree - the `add` method is O(n), so adding n elements is O(n^2). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree

Comment: Thank you, but it's interesting in c++ i got a much better time with the same data input

Comment: You'd have to post your C++ code too, otherwise we wouldn't be able to compare the two implementations.

Comment: I post c++ code